# Django SessionWizardView get_template_names() issue

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

If I use the template_name variable, my SessionWizardView works like a pycharm!

I am having troubles with the get_template_names() method provided by the SessionWizardView.

My first template using the get_template_names() method renders perfectly displaying the correct url.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/wow/character_creation/
```

I submit the form, and my second form using the get_template_name() method renders perfectly displaying the correct url and form.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/wow/character_creation/
```

I submit my second form, or if I press the prev step or first step, the following url is displayed

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/character_creation/
```

Here is the error message:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/character_creation/
```

Anyone having a reason why the /wow/ part of my url has been removed when submitting the second form?  Is there a bug in the get_template_names() method?

Here is my views.py

```
FORMS = [
("0", wow.forms.CharacterCreationForm1),
("1", wow.forms.CharacterCreationForm2),
("2", wow.forms.CharacterCreationForm3),
```

]

```
TEMPLATES = {
"0": "wow/character_creation_form_1.html",
"1": "wow/character_creation_form_2.html",
"2": "wow/character_creation_form_3.html",
```

}

```
class CharacterWizard(SessionWizardView):
    instance = None
    #template_name = "wow/character_creation_form_1.html"

# Requires the user to be logged in for every instance of the form wizard
# as-view() *urls.py* creates an instance called dispatch().  Dispatch is used to relay information
@method_decorator(login_required)
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.instance = CharacterCreation()
    return super(CharacterWizard, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

def get_form_instance(self, step):
    return self.instance

def get_template_names(self):
    #Custom templates for the different steps
    return [TEMPLATES[self.steps.current]]

def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
    self.instance.character_creation_user = self.request.user
    self.instance.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/wow/home/')
```

Here is my url.py

url(r'^character_creation/$', CharacterWizard.as_view(FORMS), name='character_creation'),

Thank you guys!

Comment: There is no `/wow/` in the url pattern. Is that the base URLs.py, or are you including it?

Comment: Your question would be clearer if you fixed the indentation.

Comment: Also, what are the contents of the first and second template?

Answer (score 0):

In my second and third templates, my form is now `action="/character_creation/"` instead of `/wow/character_creation/`.